# Хорошие книги для изучения ASP.NET MVC + workflow + jquery + ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, книги

Подскажите книги. Можно и на английском, азы есть, но хочется поглубже окунуться в эту стихию.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги по C# и другая литература](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

Онлайн-руководство по [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) MVC 4 - http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/index.php

Professional [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) MVC 4 - на амазоне - [www.amazon.com/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-Wrox-Guides/dp/111834846X/ref=pd_sim_b_1](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-Wrox-Guides/dp/111834846X/ref=pd_sim_b_1)

Programming [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) MVC 4: Developing Real-World Web Applications with [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) MVC - то же на амазоне - http://www.amazon.com/Programming-ASP-NET-MVC-Developing-Applications/dp/1449320317/ref=pd_sim_b_1